# How to do Scroll effect on change of focus on page elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I move focus to  different buttons on page programmatically via javascript. What I need to do is whenever page scrolls due to change of focus to different element, up or down the page, it should scroll with a slow motion effect rather than just the quick scroll.

How could I achieve this effect globally with jquery ?

Comment: use animate. http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: I created a example _for you_: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5csK/). Unfortunately listentening to `focus` or `blur` and stopping event bubbling does not prevent the browser from focussing/blurring. I'd suggest to write a function that first scrolls smoothly and then focusses the element. This also has the advantage that the user will recognize the focus change and thus the input element.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
Would it not be possible to do this:

```
$('#example-button-id').on('focus', function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top + 'px' }, 500);
}
```

Where the 500 is the amount of time in ms.

Comment: This works (only in Chrome ~33). In Firefox 26-28, it does not _smootly_ scroll. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5csK/1/)